# In python, how to get the minimum value of a column and showing some others value of that row and diferent columns

Tags: python, pandas

in a python exercise I am asked to get the minimum value of a column dataframe called 'IMC' and show also the columns name, position, IMC and club of the player with less IMC. I am trying something like these but it is not working at the time.

```
jugador_mas_delgado = df_4['IMC'].min([['nombre','Posición','IMC','Club']]

jugador_mas_delgado
```

Comment: If you post some sample data you will get an answer faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you have phrased your question, I think the following code might do the job for you?

```py
df_4.loc[df_4["IMC"] == df_4["IMC"].min()]
```

If you got any doubts please feel free to ping in the comments.